# Edit a view of an already deployed asp.net MVC5 application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.net MVC5 application which is already deployed on an IIS server. Now I want to make some changes on a view, very light updates. I'm wondering if this is feasible. Am I running any risks of doing that?

Answers are appreciated.

Comment: What or  why are you hesitant  about code changes? Is it the deployment post production release or how to test or who can make the chance or something else? What are you really asking here?

Comment: I guess you mean making manual changes to the deployed files?Of course that is not the recommended way to do, but you could. Make a backup of the file if you're worried

Comment: @Hanno Yes. I need to change a link of an iframe. That's it.

Comment: So you want to change one of the razor views and not the underlying code / model? Follow your normal change procedure (develop, test, deploy etc.) and at deploy time push just the razor view and not the code behind. That goes for your test and UAT environments as well as the production environment as then you are testing the release for this change as well.

Comment: @Igor Got it Thanks!